# Insert HTML into HTML page via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a client who develops some equipment with embedded web-servers that allow the end user to configure the device. The current interface for this doesn't match the bigger company 'Style Guide' and hence they've come to me to 'tart-it-up' substantially.

The problem is, that there is only 24K to fit in 7 web pages including JS, images and CSS. Plus the base firmware, only allows for HTML, ero, CSS and PNG, file formats.

Now, I've got most of the site done minus a few things, within this 24K but I really need to shave off as much data baggage as possible to give me capacity to include the images, and the final page. So literally every tiny Kb of data from a file is crucial.

I've done all the usual things like minification of all the files, but I'm still in need of trimming off more.

These has lead me to the following idea. Every page has the same footer:

```
<div class="footerContainer">
     Copyright &copy; <a href="http://url/"> Company</a> 2014. All rights reserved.
</div>
```

So I now want to place this in a separate html file and replace it with a single line of JS that then calls in the html snippet /.html file.

If the system allowed for external JS files I simply do a chunk of .js to replace a know div in the footer. But that's not possible. So, is there a way to write in JS, "insert external (html) file here"?

If this is concise enough it would at least trim off some of the size of each html page.

### Key facts

24k max size

No JS files allowed or available

No external libraries

HTML minified already

Existing JS minified already

CSS minified already

No server side tech

Comment: you can use jquery.load() for that https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Grumpy: jQuery, on its own, wouldn't fit in the space the OP says he has, much less alongside the content he says already barely fits.

Comment: why you want to insert html from external file in clint using js, why you don't include that partial html in server side?

Comment: Im not sure if javascript can read external files on its own without expansions like jQuery, but if it cant, you can create a js file with ur footer as a string variable and link the js file to all your pages and then just srt your foooter innerHtml as that string variable

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/ this may help.

Comment: @Grumpy I cant use JQuery so thats out of the question

Comment: @Epsil0neR There is no serverside technology.

Comment: @Banana As mentioned and now emphasised the firmaware doesn't allow for js files. All existing js is the physical html pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the embedded web server supports any form of server-side include, that would probably be the way to go.

If you really want to do it in JS, it's trivial to do and there's no need to read a separate file. <s>In your shared JavaScript (I assume you have a JavaScript file shared between the pages):</s>

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'footerContainer'; // <== Surely that class name could be shorter?
div.innerHTML = 'Copyright &copy; <a href="http://url/"> Company</a> 2014. All rights reserved.';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Or a bit smaller:

```
var d=document,f=d.createElement('div');
f.className='footerContainer';
f.innerHTML='Copyright &copy; <a href="http://url/"> Company</a> 2014. All rights reserved.';
d.body.appendChild(f);
```

*(Strikeout above because you've said you can't use external JS files [that is one awful environment you're working in!], and of course repeating the above for each page is much larger than the relevant markup would be.)*

The closest I can get in JavaScript to load a file (`f.html`), using the dreaded `with` construct, is slightly longer than the footer, unless the URL in the footer is *really* long (and this doesn't take into account the fact you're shortening class names):

```
<!-- The shortest I can get the inline JavaScript to insert a file -->
<script>with(new XMLHttpRequest){onload=function(){document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",responseText)};open("GET","f.html",false);send()}</script>
<!-- Your footer, for comparison (scroll to the right to see how much longer the JavaScript is -->
<div class="footerContainer">Copyright &copy; <a href="http://url/"> Company</a> 2014. All rights reserved.</div>
```

A non-JS approach using a separate file would be an `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="footer.html"></iframe>
```

...where your HTML is in `footer.html`. You'll need to add some styling (in your CSS) for the `iframe` so it combines seamlessly with the page.

Comment: Plus trim off few characters by replacing var div with var d and document with another var :P

Comment: @PeteTNT: LOL, was just doing that. :-)

Comment: Hah and I was editing in to suggest to setting document as another var :)

Comment: @PeteTNT Good point. I could shorten all my id's and classes to save a few kb sitewide. Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can't sue external .js files so I'd have to do this in the actual pages. Therefore I think even the shorter version would take up more data than the original footer.

Comment: @PhillHealey: Of course, if you have to repeat it in every page. Why in heaven's name can't you use external JS files? Anyway, server-side includes or an iframe should do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well because the firmware does accept js files. The webserver is embedded so everything get melded into a flashable image.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I am very sure.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The useable file types are expressly given in the Firmware hex files. Ive no idea why this is, other than perhaps to stop end users from flashing extra bits on that could perhaps mask the true identity of the devices. Perhaps.

Comment: @PhillHealey I think you are in some kind of web developer purgatory

Comment: @PhillHealey: Well...you *could* store it at `x.html` (`script` tags don't care about the file extension and assume JavaScript unless you use the `type` attribute, regardless of what the server says they are), but that would be pretty extreme. :-) So `iframe`, then, or save the space elsewhere (shorter class names, for instance). (And I'm with Pete on the whole purgatory thing...)

Comment: @PeteTNT But you've gotta love a challenge right? It's what makes us lowly programmer / dev types feel awesome, if only for 5mins... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ill take a look at that suggestion. Although for now, Im stripping back all classes and id's to three letters or less names. Also going to switch classes to id's where feasible too. Then minify everything and see what I end up with. But the renaming has definitely saved a few characters worth of data per page.

Comment: @PhillHealey: Yeah, sadly the closest I can get with inline JavaScript is slightly longer than the footer (not all that much, mind, but longer). Just for completeness, added it above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the effort it's much appreciated. I may be able to use it elsewhere to trim a tiny bit off.